# Application Migration from Windows 2003 Server to CentOS

Tags: linux, spring, jakarta-ee, centos, windows-server-2003

After the migration of our java application to a Linux server, we've got almost nothing working!

We can login to the server, but when data gets loaded from the database, we get an exception, and nothing gets loaded! We get a huge exception stacktrace! We use spring, maven, hibernate and other frameworks.. We don't know what to check to make it work now! I think it is something that has a DB-Background that causes the problem. Our DB-Server is a Microsoft SQL Server Enterprise Edition (64-bit), running on a Windows NT Operating System.

Here is the stacktrace:

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException:
>   Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
>   org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open
>   connection    at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:427)
>   ~[spring-orm-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:371)
>   ~[spring-tx-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:334)
>   ~[spring-tx-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:105)
>   ~[spring-tx-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
>   ~[spring-aop-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
>   ~[spring-aop-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]     at
>   com.sun.proxy.$Proxy690.sizeForFindTuples(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   ~[na:1.7.0_71]    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>   ~[na:1.7.0_71]    at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   ~[na:1.7.0_71]    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>   ~[na:1.7.0_71]    at
>   org.apache.wicket.proxy.LazyInitProxyFactory$JdkHandler.invoke(LazyInitProxyFactory.java:435)
>   ~[wicket-ioc-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]     at
>   com.sun.proxy.$Proxy694.sizeForFindTuples(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]    at
>   redb.main.modules.sample.view.overview.OverviewDataProvider.size(OverviewDataProvider.java:74)
>   ~[OverviewDataProvider.class:na]  at
>   org.apache.wicket.markup.repeater.data.DataViewBase.internalGetItemCount(DataViewBase.java:142)
>   ~[wicket-core-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]    at
>   org.apache.wicket.markup.repeater.AbstractPageableView.getItemCount(AbstractPageableView.java:235)
>   ~[wicket-core-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]    at
>   org.apache.wicket.markup.repeater.AbstractPageableView.getRowCount(AbstractPageableView.java:216)
>   ~[wicket-core-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]    at
>   org.apache.wicket.markup.repeater.AbstractPageableView.getViewSize(AbstractPageableView.java:314)
>   ~[wicket-core-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]    at
>   org.apache.wicket.markup.repeater.AbstractPageableView.getItemModels(AbstractPageableView.java:99)
>   ~[wicket-core-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]    at
>   org.apache.wicket.markup.repeater.RefreshingView.onPopulate(RefreshingView.java:93)
>   ~[wicket-core-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]    at
>   org.apache.wicket.markup.repeater.AbstractRepeater.onBeforeRender(AbstractRepeater.java:116)
>   ~[wicket-core-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]    at
>   org.apache.wicket.markup.repeater.AbstractPageableView.onBeforeRender(AbstractPageableView.java:115)
>   ~[wicket-core-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]    at
>   org.apache.wicket.Component.internalBeforeRender(Component.java:922)
>   ~[wicket-core-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]    at
>   org.apache.wicket.Component.beforeRender(Component.java:990)
>   ~[wicket-core-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]    at
>   org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onBeforeRenderChildren(MarkupContainer.java:1681)
>   ~[wicket-core-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]    ... 90 common frames omitted Caused
>   by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
>   org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open
>   connection    at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1377)
>   ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1300)
>   ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1387)
>   ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:62)
>   ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]    at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.DefaultJpaDialect.beginTransaction(DefaultJpaDialect.java:70)
>   ~[spring-orm-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.beginTransaction(HibernateJpaDialect.java:59)
>   ~[spring-orm-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:377)
>   ~[spring-orm-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]     ... 114 common frames
>   omitted Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could
>   not open connection   at
>   org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:304)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:169)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:67)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:160)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1395)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:59)
>   ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]    ... 117 common
>   frames omitted Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Unable to open a test
>   connection to the given database. JDBC url =
>   jdbc:sqlserver://******\***:****;DatabaseName=RE_****            , username =
>   Re_****. Terminating connection pool (set lazyInit to true if you
>   expect to start your database after your app). Original Exception:
>   ------ com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host  has failed. java.net.UnknownHostException: 
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.loginWithoutFailover(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
>     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)     at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)  at
>   com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP.obtainRawInternalConnection(BoneCP.java:363)
>     at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP.(BoneCP.java:416)     at
>   com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource.getConnection(BoneCPDataSource.java:120)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:70)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:292)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:297)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:169)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:67)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:160)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1395)
>     at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:59)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.DefaultJpaDialect.beginTransaction(DefaultJpaDialect.java:70)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.beginTransaction(HibernateJpaDialect.java:59)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:377)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:371)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:334)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:105)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy690.sizeForFindTuples(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.apache.wicket.proxy.LazyInitProxyFactory$JdkHandler.invoke(LazyInitProxyFactory.java:435)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy694.sizeForFindTuples(Unknown Source)    at
>   redb.main.modules.sample.view.overview.OverviewDataProvider.size(OverviewDataProvider.java:74)
>     at
>   org.apache.wicket.markup.repeater.data.DataViewBase.internalGetItemCount(DataViewBase.java:142)
>     at
>   org.apache.wicket.markup.repeater.AbstractPageableView.getItemCount(AbstractPageableView.java:235)
>     at
>   org.apache.wicket.markup.repeater.AbstractPageableView.getRowCount(AbstractPageableView.java:216)
>     at
>   org.apache.wicket.markup.repeater.AbstractPageableView.getViewSize(AbstractPageableView.java:314)
>     at
>   org.apache.wicket.markup.repeater.AbstractPageableView.getItemModels(AbstractPageableView.java:99)
>     at
>   org.apache.wicket.markup.repeater.RefreshingView.onPopulate(RefreshingView.java:93)
>     at
>   org.apache.wicket.markup.repeater.AbstractRepeater.onBeforeRender(AbstractRepeater.java:116)
>     at
>   org.apache.wicket.markup.repeater.AbstractPageableView.onBeforeRender(AbstractPageableView.java:115)
>     at
>   org.apache.wicket.Component.internalBeforeRender(Component.java:922)
>     at org.apache.wicket.Component.beforeRender(Component.java:990)     at
>   org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onBeforeRenderChildren(MarkupContainer.java:1681)
>     at org.apache.wicket.Component.onBeforeRender(Component.java:3843)
>     at
>   org.apache.wicket.Component.internalBeforeRender(Component.java:922)
>     at org.apache.wicket.Component.beforeRender(Component.java:990)     at
>   org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onBeforeRenderChildren(MarkupContainer.java:1681)
>     at org.apache.wicket.Component.onBeforeRender(Component.java:3843)
>     at
>   org.apache.wicket.Component.internalBeforeRender(Component.java:922)
>     at org.apache.wicket.Component.beforeRender(Component.java:990)     at
>   org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onBeforeRenderChildren(MarkupContainer.java:1681)
>     at org.apache.wicket.Component.onBeforeRender(Component.java:3843)
>     at
>   org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.onBeforeRender(Form.java:1743)
>     at
>   org.apache.wicket.Component.internalBeforeRender(Component.java:922)
>     at org.apache.wicket.Component.beforeRender(Component.java:990)     at
>   org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onBeforeRenderChildren(MarkupContainer.java:1681)
>     at org.apache.wicket.Component.onBeforeRender(Component.java:3843)
>     at
>   org.apache.wicket.Component.internalBeforeRender(Component.java:922)
>     at org.apache.wicket.Component.beforeRender(Component.java:990)     at
>   org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onBeforeRenderChildren(MarkupContainer.java:1681)
>     at org.apache.wicket.Component.onBeforeRender(Component.java:3843)
>     at org.apache.wicket.Page.onBeforeRender(Page.java:798)     at
>   org.apache.wicket.Component.internalBeforeRender(Component.java:922)
>     at org.apache.wicket.Component.beforeRender(Component.java:990)     at
>   org.apache.wicket.Component.internalPrepareForRender(Component.java:2213)
>     at org.apache.wicket.Page.internalPrepareForRender(Page.java:241)   at
>   org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2302)   at
>   org.apache.wicket.Page.renderPage(Page.java:1010)     at
>   org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.WebPageRenderer.renderPage(WebPageRenderer.java:116)
>     at
>   org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.WebPageRenderer.respond(WebPageRenderer.java:249)
>     at
>   org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.RenderPageRequestHandler.respond(RenderPageRequestHandler.java:165)
>     at
>   org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:861)
>     at
>   org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerStack.execute(RequestHandlerStack.java:64)
>     at
>   org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(RequestCycle.java:261)
>     at
>   org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:218)
>     at
>   org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:289)
>     at
>   org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequestCycle(WicketFilter.java:259)
>     at
>   org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:201)
>     at
>   org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:282)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:180)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:155)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:931)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn.invoke(SingleSignOn.java:289)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProcessor.process(AjpAprProcessor.java:197)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1822)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>
> ### at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor259.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source) ~[na:na]  at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>   ~[na:1.7.0_71]    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
>   ~[na:1.7.0_71]    at
>   com.jolbox.bonecp.PoolUtil.generateSQLException(PoolUtil.java:192)
>   ~[bonecp-0.8.0.RELEASE.jar:na]    at
>   com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP.(BoneCP.java:422)
>   ~[bonecp-0.8.0.RELEASE.jar:na]    at
>   com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource.getConnection(BoneCPDataSource.java:120)
>   ~[bonecp-0.8.0.RELEASE.jar:na]    at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:70)
>   ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:292)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:297)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]     ... 122 common frames
>   omitted Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException:
>   The TCP/IP connection to the host  has failed.
>   java.net.UnknownHostException:    at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(Unknown
>   Source) ~[sqljdbc-1.0.jar:na]     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(Unknown
>   Source) ~[sqljdbc-1.0.jar:na]     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.loginWithoutFailover(Unknown
>   Source) ~[sqljdbc-1.0.jar:na]     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(Unknown
>   Source) ~[sqljdbc-1.0.jar:na]     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
>   ~[sqljdbc-1.0.jar:na]     at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
>   ~[na:1.7.0_71]    at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
>   ~[na:1.7.0_71]    at
>   com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP.obtainRawInternalConnection(BoneCP.java:363)
>   ~[bonecp-0.8.0.RELEASE.jar:na]    at
>   com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP.(BoneCP.java:416)
>   ~[bonecp-0.8.0.RELEASE.jar:na]    ... 126 common frames omitted

Comment: Have you read the stack trace? `SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host has failed. java.net.UnknownHostException` looks quite clear to me, your host isn't in the hosts file or at least cannot be resolved from your server.

Comment: thanks! but where could I find the hosts file?

Comment: should I change that in the properties.xml, where the jdbc properties are?